# MongoDB Query to Retrieve Objects with True Status in Nested Menu Elements

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with documents structured like the following:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65906e6a9bc35431ac107e4a"
  },
  "permissions": {
    "menu_elements": {
      "home": {
        "name": "HOME",
        "status": true
      },
      "contact": {
        "name": "CONTACT",
        "status": true
      },
      "about": {
        "name": "ABOUT",
        "status": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to write a MongoDB query to retrieve all objects where the status is true within the permissions->menu_elements nested array. Can someone assist me in crafting the appropriate query for this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have tried the following PHP code to retrieve documents from MongoDB where the status is true within the permissions.menu_elements array:

```
$permissions = $db->system->find([
    'permissions.menu_elements' => [
        '$elemMatch' => [
            'status' => true
        ]
    ]
], ['permissions.menu_elements.$' => 1]);
```

However, this code didn't produce the expected results. I was expecting to retrieve documents where any element within the permissions.menu_elements array has a status of true. I would appreciate any insights or corrections regarding the syntax of my MongoDB query.

Comment: Did you know that `menu_elements` is an object and not an array?